# Does the Contact Layout Editor extension allow creation of tab layouts?

Tags: contact-layout-editor

I need to make a tab with a LOT of custom fields and making it usable will require some careful design. These fields will be relevant only for a small subset of users in my database so I prefer to keep it off the summary page altogether. My ideal design is to have a tab on the contact record that I can design using the functionality of the Contact Layout Editor.

However, I am currently in a CiviSpark instance and so installing the extension will require migration to a new instance, managing my own hosting, etc. I have other reasons for making this change eventually, am not quite ready, but the Contact Layout Editor could push me toward doing it.

I have read the [documentation](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.contactlayout) but can't tell from that.

Experienced users of this extension, can you tell me if I can use it to create layouts for contact tabs, or does it create layout options for the summary page only?

Comment: "These fields will be relevant only for a small subset of users in my database so I prefer to keep it off the summary page altogether". if you had your subset set up as a 'sub type' then they would only show on the summary page for those types - just fyi

Comment: "or does it create layout options for the summary page only", I believe yes only the summary page. but combined with using sub-types you may still easily achieve what you want

Comment: Thanks @petednz-fuzion! This is a good idea and I will do it if it is my only option (I would not to because they are not mutually exclusive to other types so I would be limiting myself, but it probably is worth it).